# Custom div in Shopify Page is Set to 100% Width, but Will Not Fill Container

Tags: html, css, shopify

I'm trying to implement [this script](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/comment-page-1/#comments), into a shopify page.

Here is my progress: [www.mak-home.com/pages/the-verve](http://www.mak-home.com/pages/the-verve).

I've got the javascript to work, but I cannot figure out the sizing issues.
Ideally, I would like the photo layout to have 100% width - edge to edge.

I know that is not possible right now with the main-content-wrapper that applies to all shopify pages restricting my width. (this is also something I'm trying to figure out - how to make just this one page full width).

I did do a test where I made all pages 100% width (with no content wrapper) and the size of the photo grid did not change. I'm using the stock css included in the download and copied the structure of the html in the index3.html file.

I can't seem to pinpoint why this thing wont get bigger.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is some code to help:

```js
{% if template contains 'page' %}
    {{ 'demo.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
    {{ 'style.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
    {{ 'fallback.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  
    {{ 'modernizr.custom.26633.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
    {{ 'jquery-1.8.3.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
    
  
  
  {% endif %}
  
  

</head>


...


{% if template contains 'page' %}
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function() {
   
    $( '#ri-grid' ).gridrotator( {
     rows  : 3,
     columns  : 15,
     animType : 'fadeInOut',
                    maxStep : 2,
     interval : 2000,
                    preventClick : false,
                  
                    w1024 : {
      rows : 5,
      columns : 6
     },
                    w480 : {
      rows : 6,
      columns : 4
     },
                    w320 : {
      rows : 7,
      columns : 4
     },
                    w240 : {
      rows : 7,
      columns : 3
     },
                  
                  
                  
                  
    } );
   
   });
</script>  
  
  {{ 'jquery.gridrotator.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  
  {% endif %}
```

```css
.ri-grid{
 margin: 30px auto 30px;
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
    
}

.ri-grid ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* Clear floats by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */

.ri-grid ul:before,
.ri-grid ul:after{
 content: '';
    display: table;
}

.ri-grid ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.ri-grid ul {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
} 

.ri-grid ul li {
 -webkit-perspective: 400px;
 -moz-perspective: 400px;
 -o-perspective: 400px;
 -ms-perspective: 400px;
 perspective: 400px; 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #000;
}

.ri-grid ul li a{
 display: block;
 outline: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
 -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #333;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
}

/* Grid wrapper sizes */
.ri-grid-size-1{
 width: 55%;
}
.ri-grid-size-2{
 width: 100%;
}
.ri-grid-size-3{
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

/* Shadow style */
.ri-shadow:after,
.ri-shadow:before{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -2;
 bottom: 15px;
 left: 10px;
 width: 50%;
 height: 20%;
 max-width: 300px;
 max-height: 100px;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.ri-shadow:after{
 right: 10px;
 left: auto;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
 transform: rotate(3deg);
}

.ri-grid-loading:after,
.ri-grid-loading:before{
 display: none;
}

.ri-loading-image{
 display: none;
}

.ri-grid-loading .ri-loading-image{
 position: relative;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 left: 50%;
 margin: 100px 0 0 -15px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="ri-grid" class="ri-grid ri-grid-size-3">
     
     <ul>
      
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.48.58_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.49.19_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.49.10_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.52.01_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.54.46_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.54.24_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.53.34_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.53.18_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.53.03_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.52.33_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.52.18_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.51.33_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.51.20_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.51.11_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.50.51_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.50.37_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.50.15_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.50.05_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.49.59_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.49.52_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.49.43_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.49.36_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/files/Screen_Shot_2015-10-07_at_1.49.29_PM.png?17299102800213359554"/></a></li>




     </ul>
    </div>
    
   <div>
```

Comment: NOTE: when I change the containing <div> to a span - the width increases to 100%.  But the sizing does not work out - the code no longer makes all three rows of pictures with the same amount of columns and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues all over the place with CSS that restricts the width of things. 
You can fix the shopify CSS by altering your theme. It looks like the plugin styles restrict the widget's width with http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0784/0657/t/63/assets/fallback.css?13939960370831423999 having :

```
.ri-grid{
   width: 600px;
}
```

It looks like you should reverse the order of your stylesheet tags so that demo.css rules override equivalent styles from the other two and style.css overrides fallback.css.

```
{{ 'fallback.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'style.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'demo.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Comment: Thank you for this btw I forgot to mention